# How to save as slide Powerpoint without blurry text

Tags: powerpoint

I have 90 slide powerpoint, i want to save as .jpg but the text in result jpg is blurry not high res. My questions is how to save as .jpg slde powerpoint without blurry text.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this page on my PPT FAQ site:Improve PowerPoint's GIF, BMP, PNG, JPG export resolution
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00052_Improve_PowerPoint-s_GIF-_BMP-_PNG-_JPG_export_resolution.htm  I'm afraid LambChops is mistaken. PPT can save up to 3000 pixel wide images (wider still if you have 2013 SP1 or higher)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to produce high-res JPG images, PowerPoint does not allow you to save to a very high resolution. For higher resolution JPGs, your best bet is to save as a loss-less image type, such as PNG, and then use a conversion tool that will allow you to create high-res JPG images.